# Integral test for convergence proof

Tags: real-analysis, integration, sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence

Can someone help me understand this proof?

[image]

I don't understand why

$f(n+1) = \int_n^{n+1}{f(n+1)}$

Thank you so much and I am sorry I have nothing else to contribute as I'm fearing it is a rather basic misunderstanding.

Comment: Integrating a constant function gives you that constant times length of the integration interval, which is 1 in this case.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The variable here is $x$ not $n$, so $f(n+1)$ is regarded as a constant. Thus,

$\int_{n}^{n+1} f(n+1)dx=f(n+1)\int_n^{n+1} dx=f(n+1)[(n+1)-n]=f(n+1)$

QED.

Answer (score 2):

$\int_n^{n+1}f(n+1)\,dx=f(n+1)(n+1-n)$, because you are integrating with respect to $x$ a function that doesn't depend on $x$ (i.e. a constant).